# Permanently save Netlink Sockets changes

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, interprocess, netlink

In order to set Network Interfaces on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I've recently developed a C program which takes advantage of Netlink Sockets for interprocess communication between User-Space and Kernel-Space. 
After having successfully changed the ip/gateway/netmask addresses (emulating some iproute2 functions), I need to permanently save these changes. Indeed, after reboot these changes are dropped. 
I don't want to change the /etc/network/interfaces file nor use Network Manager, but programmatically communicate with the Linux Kernel.

There is any way of doing it?

Regards

Comment: `but programmatically communicate with the Linux Kernel.` - Like many other OS kernels, Linux kernel itself doesn't store **configuration**. So I am not sure what you want from the "communication with the Linux kernel".

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm a newbie of Linux Kernel OS and the fact that it doesn't store configurations permanently it is new for me. Then, what happens with Network Mananer when you set a static ip for example? It saves configurations on a file and the Kernel read it at every reboot?

Comment: `It saves configurations on a file and the Kernel read it at every reboot?` - Something like that. I am not an expert in network configuration.